# How to obtain a directory extension in Azure AD using MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to query a custom directory extension that was added to our user object in Azure AD. I am using the solution found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web).

I'm able to get the property using the UserProfileController and updating the Model to have our custom extension property (see the two code snippets below).

**Models/UserProfile.cs**

```cs
public class UserProfile
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string extension_ExtId_ExtName { get; set; }
}
```

**View/UserProfile.cshtml**

```html
@model App.Models.UserProfile
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Display Name</td>
        <td>@Model.DisplayName</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>@Model.GivenName</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>@Model.Surname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Employee Id</td>
        <td>@Model.extension_ExtId_ExtName</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "AuthorizationRequired")
{
    <p>You have to sign-in to see your profile. Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "Index", "UserProfile", new { reauth = true }, null) to sign-in.</p>
}
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "UnexpectedError")
{
    <p>An unexpected error occurred while retrieving your profile.  Please try again.  You may need to sign-in.</p>
}
```

My goal is to have the extension `extension_ExtId_ExtName` appear on a list of users. I am trying to use the solution's `UsersController` and view to obtain this information, but it appears that the Microsoft Graph API User model cannot be modified. The model is set to be of an `IEnumerable<User>` for which the Microsoft Graph Client controls.

How do I add my custom extension so that I can retrieve it from the User object as well?

I've confirmed that I can obtain it via the user object by going to the Graph Explorer and setting my request URL to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{user@email.com}')?select=extension_EXTENSION-ID_extensionName`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem here is that you're conflating two different API. There is the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) and the [Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api); these are two entirely different APIs. While there is a lot of functional overlap between them, calls are not interchangeable between them.

I'd suggest taking a look at these Microsoft Graph API samples instead:

- [aspnet-snippets-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample)
- [aspnet-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample)
- [aspnet-connect-rest-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample)

Comment: I see what you're saying and I'm now reviewing my code because part of it references the MS Graph API whereas another part references Azure AD Graph API. I would prefer to use MS Graph API in my project, so I'm going to focus in this area. I realized that my UserProfileController relies on MS Graph and the UserController relies on Azure AD. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I've attempted to use the 'aspnet-snippets-example' and got it work beautifully, but now I'm up against trying to pull the custom directory extension as shown in the graph URL I posted earlier. Again, I tried updating the ViewModel for the solution to include the directory extension, but I wasn't able to obtain it still because it's referencing the Graph User object. Help?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `Extensions` property of the [`User`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Models/Generated/User.cs).

Comment: I queried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/extensions`, no results are returned. I did more reading on the development website and I found this: *Azure AD supports a similar type of extensions, known as directory schema extensions, on a few directoryObject resources. While you must use Azure AD Graph API to create and manage the definitions of directory schema extensions, you can use Microsoft Graph API to add, get, update and delete data in the properties of these extensions* How do I GET the data from `extension_EXTENSION-ID_extensionName`. Is this possible?

Comment: I resulted in using Azure Active Directory Graph API to obtain the extension that I needed. I tried multiple times via Microsoft Graph API without much luck unless I used the beta version. I ended up creating a ViewModel that accepted a list of properties that included the extension I needed from the user object to be passed back to the application.

Comment: Did you end up calling AAD Graph to get this data?  If you already know the name of the AAD directory schema extensions, you should be able to fetch that data through Microsoft Graph (as you proved through Graph Explorer)... The call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/extensions` is part of the new Microsoft Graph extensions capability, which is slightly different.  In Microsoft Graph we have open extensions, schema extensions AND the ability to get/set the older format AAD directory schema extension data.  It's the latter that I think you are trying to do.